# x:Bind Item in ListView to ViewModel

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

You know when you stare at something long enough it doesn't really make sense any more... I am trying to bind the background property of a listview item to whether it is part of a collection in the viewmodel. Here is a simplified version of what I'm working with:

```
<Grid>

    <ListView x:Name="AirportListView"
              SelectionMode="None"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ItemClick="AirportListView_ItemClick">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">

                <Grid Padding="16">

                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" />

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>            

    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

and:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyAirports { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        AirportListView.ItemsSource = new List<string>()
        {
            "EDDB",
            "LGIR",
            "EHAM",
            "LFPO",
            "EGKK"
        };
    }

    private void AirportListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickedItem is string clickedAirport)
        {
            if (MyAirports.Contains(clickedAirport))
                MyAirports.Remove(clickedAirport);
            else
                MyAirports.Add(clickedAirport);
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally what I would like to achieve is to bind the background of the grid in the datatemplate so that it is a different colour when an item is part of MyAirports. I just haven't been able to figure out how to do this using x:Bind or Binding. I can think of a few more long winded ways to achieve the same thing but wondered if there is perhaps a more elegant solution with data binding.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the collection that goes to ItemsSource a richer class than just a string. It should contain the property IsMyAirport, then it can be bound to each ListViewItem as well to update its background.

```
<Page ...
    xmlns:local="using:UwpQuestions.Views"
    xmlns:common="using:UwpQuestions.Common">
    <Page.Resources>
        <common:MyBgConverter x:Key="myBgConverter"/>
    </Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="AirportList"
          SelectionMode="None"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Airports}"
          ItemClick="AirportListView_ItemClick">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:AirportItem">
                <Grid Padding="16" Width="150" Background="{x:Bind IsMyAirport, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource myBgConverter}}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

With the following code behind:

```
public sealed partial class AirportListView : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> MyAirports { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<AirportItem> Airports { get; set; }

    public AirportListView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Airports = new ObservableCollection<AirportItem>
        {
            new AirportItem {Name = "EDDB"},
            new AirportItem {Name = "LGIR"},
            new AirportItem {Name = "LFPO"},
            new AirportItem {Name = "EGKK"}
        };
    }

    private void AirportListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickedItem is AirportItem clickedAirport)
        {
            if (MyAirports.Contains(clickedAirport.Name))
            {
                MyAirports.Remove(clickedAirport.Name);
                clickedAirport.IsMyAirport = false;
            }
            else
            {
                MyAirports.Add(clickedAirport.Name);
                clickedAirport.IsMyAirport = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class AirportItem : BindableBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty<string>(ref _name, value); }
    }

    private bool _isMyAirport = false;
    public bool IsMyAirport
    {
        get { return _isMyAirport; }
        set { SetProperty<bool>(ref _isMyAirport, value); }
    }
}
```

AirportItem uses BindableBase to notify the ListView of when properties in the class change. It implements INotifyPropertyChanged. If you're not familiar with it, you should read up on XAML databinding.

And, it also uses the MyBgConverter (that Laith defined) to change the bool value into a different background color.

Finally, with the IsMyAirport property on the class, you may not need a separate MyAirports string list. I didn't remove it because I wasn't sure if you were using it for something else. But your logic in AirportListView_ItemClick can be changed to just use the IsMyAirport bool rather than the MyAirports list.

Comment: Thanks Pedro, yes this is a simplified version of what I am actually trying to do, but I have managed to do it by as you say 'baking in' a property called IsMyAirport to the original class and making sure that stays updated with changes to the collection. Now will try getting it working in my app. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Create a converter that converts `bool` to a `SolidColorBrush` and use that in the binding.

```
<ListView Background="{x:Bind IsPartOfMyAirports, Converter={StaticResource MyBgConverter}}">
...
</ListView>
```

Your view model would be responsible for notifying the change for `IsPartOfMyAirports`.

Your converter would look something like this:

```
public class MyBgConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var b = (bool)value;
        var color = b ? Colors.Yellow : Colors.Green;

        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Laith, thanks for the suggestion. The idea would be to bind the background of each individual item so I'm not sure where to create `IsPartOfMyAirports` so that it could be updated by each item.